# Use ZF1 Model into ZF2 project

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, migration, models

I'm working on a project where i have to migrate from ZF1 to ZF2 application.
I must not rewrite the code from ZF1. I have added ZF1 librarys to ZF2 project ( via composer ). SO now ZF2 recognize new classes like Zend_Db_Table_Abstract.

I have a Model :

```
namespace principal\Model;

use Zend_Db_Table_Abstract;

class Reservation extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_name = 'ws_booking';
    // ....
    public function getLigne()
    {
        try {
            $adapter = $this->getAdapter();
            // .....
            }
    }
}
```

The getAdapter called is from ZF1 ( the model extends from Zend_Db_Table_Abstract )
When i call the model from a controller i get this error : 
No adapter found for principal\Model\Reservation
[No adapter found for principal\Model\Reservation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VBbI.png)

I'm using ZF2 2.3.3
Migrating from 1.1

Is there a way to use zf2 adapter with a zf1 class. If yes how ?
How can i manage to manipulate the model?

Comment: Help please, some one  ?

Comment: have you read this guide? https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/migration/zf1_zf2_parallel.html

Answer (score 0):

In line 2, you are using the use contruct to call Zend_Db_Table_Abstract from ZF1 one. use the table abstract of ZF2 wiz 
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway;